# C++11 Simple Producer Consumer Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to teach myself multithreading and I followed this tutorial here: https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2013/spring/12300-1/labs/lab6/

If you scroll all the way to the bottom there is a sample snippet of a producer-consumer and it asks us to solve the race conditions found in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int c = 0;
    bool done = false;
    queue<int> goods;

    thread producer([&]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
            goods.push(i);
            c++;
        }

        done = true;
    });

    thread consumer([&]() {
        while (!done) {
            while (!goods.empty()) {
                goods.pop();
                c--;
            }
        }
    });

    producer.join();
    consumer.join();
    cout << "Net: " << c << endl;
}
```

The Net value at the end should be 0, here is my attempt at it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <queue>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    int c = 0;

    bool done = false;
    queue<int> goods;
    mutex mtx;  
    condition_variable cond_var;

    // thread to produce 500 elements
    thread producer([&]() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
            // lock critical secion
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);   

            goods.push(i);
            c++;
            lock.unlock();

            // notify consumer that data has been produced
            cond_var.notify_one();
        }

        // notify the consumer that it is done
        done = true;
        cond_var.notify_one();


    });

    // thread to consume all elements
    thread consumer([&]() {

        while (!done) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);   
            while (!goods.empty()) {
                goods.pop();
                c--;
            }
            // unlocks lock and wait until something in producer gets put
            cond_var.wait(lock);
        }
    });

    producer.join();
    consumer.join();
    cout << "Net: " << c << endl;
}
```

I feel like I am fundamentally missing something. I believe the biggest problem I am having is in the consumer with the cond_var.wait() because if the producer sets "done" to true then the consumer won't go back into the while(!goods.empty()). I am not sure how to fix it though.

Any hints, explanations or even different approaches would be appreciated!

Comment: I think setting `done = true;` in the producer is causing early exit of the consumer.  If you move `producer.join();` above the declaration of `thread consumer([` (simulating all work queued before the consumer starts) then the consumer does no work.

Comment: You treat the two states in consumer independantly. But they are actually both needed to define a "completed". Both "done" and `goods.empty()` must be true at the same time for you to have finished.

Comment: The `unique_lock` has a destructor that calls unlock. So you don't need to explicitly call it in `producer`.

Comment: The `condition_variable` has a wait() that includes a test for continuing.

Comment: Think about the `goods.pop();c--;` This is a simplification of `goods.pop();doSomeWork();` In real life if `doSomeWork()` is not trivial then your consumer is blocking the producer from their tasks as it is holding the lock while doing its work.

Comment: A simple(r) solution. Does it actually say consumer/producer need to work in parallel? The race condition is around `done`. Your consumer can simply wait until `done` is set then processes all the work items without further conflict.

Comment: @MartinYork Thanks for all the comments.  I'll try to address your comments. 


In the consumer while loop I changed it to while(!done && !goods.empty()) but shouldn't there be a lock somewhere while it checks goods.empty()?


not quite sure what this means "The condition_variable has a wait() that includes a test for continuing"


The reason I don't unlock after goods.pop() is because the doSomeWork() after uses the shared int variable "c" so I wouldn't want multiple threads updating it right?


The spirit of this problem is to solve it concurrently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Producer:

```
thread producer([&]() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i)
    {
        {
            // Just have a lock while interacting with shared items.
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);   
            goods.push(i);
            c++;
        }
        cond_var.notify_one();
    }

    // Lock to update shared state.
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);   
    done = true;
    cond_var.notify_one();
});
```

### Consumer

```
thread consumer([&]() {

    // This loop exits when
    //        done          => true
    //   AND  goods.empty() => true

    // Acquire lock before checking shared state.
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);

    while (!(done && goods.empty()))
    {
        // Wait until there is something in the queue to processes
        // releasing lock while we wait.
        // Break out if we are done or goods is not empty.
        cond_var.wait(lock, [&](){return done || !goods.empty();});

        // You now have the lock again, so modify shared state is allowed
        // But there is a possibility of no goods being available.
        // So let's check before doing work.
        if (!goods.empty())
        {
            goods.pop();
            c--;
        }
    }
});
```

---

Alternatively if we are simply solving for race condition. We can simply check on the state of `done` and make sure no other variables have interactions.

### Producer:

```
thread producer([&]() {

    // The consumer is not allowed to touch goods
    // until you are finished. So just use with
    // no locks.
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i)
    {
        goods.push(i);
        c++;
    }

    // Lock to update shared state.
    // Tell consumer we are ready for processing.
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);   
    done = true;
    cond_var.notify_one();
});
```

### Consumer

```
thread consumer([&]() {

    // Acquire lock before checking shared state.
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
    cond_var.wait(lock, [&](){return done;});

    // We now know the consumer has finished all updates.
    // So we can simply loop over the goods and processes them
    while (!goods.empty())
    {
        goods.pop();
        c--;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I copied over the first approach but it appears that the consumer gets stuck in an infinite loop, did it work for you? I also have a question about the consumer, after the cond_var.wait(...) you mention that we now have the lock again but I don't see that happening?

Comment: The `condition_variable` releases the lock when you call `wait()`, but re-aquires the lock before the `wait()` call returns to your code.

Comment: The `wait()` precondition function is always confusing. Maybe I got the test wrong. `!done || goods.empty()`. Try: `done || !goods.empty()` let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Ah gotcha did not realize that wait() re-acquires the lock. Changing it to done || !goods.empty() fixed it! I also had to make another minor change in the producer which was to include the c++ operation inside the curly braces with the lock otherwise the value of c was incorrect at the end. Thanks for all your help, I understand it much better now!